# validate data in controller and model, or just controller?

Tags: model-view-controller

I have the action `contlrSaveText()` in controller and the method `modelSaveText()` in model.
When the data comes from the website to the `contlrSaveText()`, I check whether the required information is received to save text, i.e. text name, text content etc. Then I call `modelSaveText()` to actually perform saving text. Do I need to validate data in this method as well or I can expect that controlled already did the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A model is only an abstract description, while a controller does the work.
Your model might have a controller on its own that take care of the data and updates the model. But that is technically a controller.
How he works with toward the outside, e.g. another controller that fills data in, is up to you how you define the interface. If your model uses relations or properties that require to be set up by the controller then you have to validate the data before inserting/accepting. But if not, then there is no point in validation and it can be skipped for performance reasons.

If you need to reject invalid data you have to think of a way how to tell the outside what whent wrong so it can respond to the error.

In your example I would go for validation, but that is just my opinion.